# How to save 2 sklearn models in one file

Tags: neural-network, pickle, joblib

[This page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) show methods to save model using either `pickle`:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> s = pickle.dumps(clf)
>>> clf2 = pickle.loads(s)
```

or `joblib`:

```
>>> from sklearn.externals import joblib
>>> joblib.dump(clf, 'filename.joblib') 
>>> clf = joblib.load('filename.joblib')
```

What if one needs to save 2 models? I can obviously save them in 2 separate files but can I save them together in one file? Is it possible to save a list which has 2 models:

```
modlist = [clf1, clf2]
```

How can this `modlist` be saved in one file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dump/load a variety of data structures using pickle. A list of sklearn fitted models, in particular, would be one example:

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
import pickle

clf1 = svm.SVC(gamma='scale')
clf2 = MultinomialNB()

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
clf1.fit(X, y)  
clf2.fit(X, y)  

filename = "models.sav"

modlist = [clf1, clf2]

s = pickle.dump(modlist, open(filename, 'wb'))

modlist_loaded = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

clf1_loaded = modlist_loaded[0]
clf2_loaded = modlist_loaded[1]

print clf1_loaded.predict(X[:10])
print clf2_loaded.predict(X[:10])
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: `gamma='scale'` needs to be omitted for SVC classifier to work here.